# React Router V6 routed component needs state/props from another routed component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hello I am using React router for my application. App.js code segment:

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Login navigate={navigate} setOverlays={setOverlays} setToken={setToken} setUser={setUser} />} />
    <Route path="/create-account" element={<CreateAccount />} />
    <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects token={token} name={user.name} jobTitle={user.jobTitle} navigate={navigate} setOverlays={setOverlays} />} />
    <Route path="/individual_project" element={<IndividualProject />} />
  </Routes>
```

The last route (/individual_project) requires props that is located in the projects component. Since I do not have access to the components in App.js how can I create this route.

I also prefer not to move the state variables from the Projects component and pass them down through props.

Comment: So maybe individual_project route should be nested in projects route

Comment: What have you tried? What is it from the `Projects` component that needs to be accessible in the `IndividualProject` component? Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for all the relevant code you are having an issue working with.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to achieve that:

- You can move the *individual_project* route inside the *Projects* component like this:

```
const Projects = () => {
...other logic
return(
 <Routes>
   <Route path="/individual_project" element={<IndividualProject />} />
 </Routes>
)
}
```

Docs here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes

- Alternatively, you could also create a context to wrap the routes. Then, you can retrieve the variables directly from the context:

```
<Context.Provider value={yourValuesToShare}>
 <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Login navigate={navigate} setOverlays={setOverlays} setToken={setToken} setUser={setUser} />} />
    <Route path="/create-account" element={<CreateAccount />} />
    <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects token={token} name={user.name} jobTitle={user.jobTitle} navigate={navigate} setOverlays={setOverlays} />} />
    <Route path="/individual_project" element={<IndividualProject />} />
 </Routes>
</Context.Provider>
```

Docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of scenarios , using `Context API` is recommended .its more precise and cleaner that the other techniques.
[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Context api is used to access state from any component so react context api is recommended